# How to create javascript while loop that breaks when value from JSON url is not null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I have the following code which reads from a url. I'd like create a while loop that runs continuously every second until data does not equal null

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$.getJSON("https://bnb.firebaseio.com/airbunny/listing_rank_data/16861909NULL.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$.getJSON("https://bnb.firebaseio.com/airbunny/listing_rank_data/16861909NULL.json", function(data) {
    while (data=='null') {
        setTimeout(function (){
        }, 5000);
    }
    console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of *while* loop here. You can create a function which can be executed with delay using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```
function getData(){
    $.getJSON("https://bnb.firebaseio.com/airbunny/listing_rank_data/16861909NULL.json", function(data) {
        if(data == null){
            setTimeout(getData, f000);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
//Initial Invocation 
getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `setTimeout` method:

```
function poll() {
    $.getJSON("https://bnb.firebaseio.com/airbunny/listing_rank_data/16861909NULL.json", function(data) {
        if (data === "null") {
            // The data is null, send a new request in 5 seconds
            window.setTimeout(poll, 5000);
        } else {
            // The data is no longer null, we don't need to continue polling
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems more likely that OP wants `data === null`, and not a string comparison. I might be wrong, as it's not completely clear from their example.